# Connect to network folder with user name and password

Tags: c#, database, file, passwords

I want to connect to the drive inside the network, but the user name and password of the answering machine are required to access the network.

What is the code that logs in while running the form?

ip: 192.168.1.8
file ip sher: //192.168.1.8\zp

user name : admin
password: 5000

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post your sensitive data. And share with us your code, not the screenshot